# How to test Kafka Consumer with Embedded-Kafka-lib, exactly with 'withRunningKafka'?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, scalatest, producer-consumer, alpakka

I should test my code for consuming all messages from kafka-server via embedded 'withRunningKafka' as shown here: https://github.com/manub/scalatest-embedded-kafka

1. I've tried to send a message to the topic via created embedded producer.
2. And I've tried to consume produced messages(created by the embedded producer) via my code in the project.

"testing with custom producer and consumer" should {

```
"work" in {

    withRunningKafka {

      1. val producer: KafkaProducer[String, String] =
               aKafkaProducer[String](valueSerializer, config)

         val topic = "topic-to-test"

         producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, "some message 1"))
         producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, "some message 2"))
         producer.close()

      2. val ok: Future[Done] = Consumer
        .committableSource(
            consumerSettings,
            Subscriptions.topics(topic))
        .map(msg => println(msg.record.value()))
        .runWith(Sink.ignore)

       ok should be (Done)
    }
}}
```

Problem is here: 'ok' doesn't give the result as 'Done'.
Generally, is my logic to test consumer correct?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

The reason `ok` is never completed with a result, because the source is waiting for possible further messages. Add `.take(2)` before map, and the source will stop after two elements letting `ok` future to be completed.

Comment: dvim unfortunately, it's not working. Is my approach to test right ?

Comment: One more thing I noticed is the type of `ok` is `Future[Done]` and you are comparing it with `Done`. You should extract the value from the future to compare. You can do that by mixing in `ScalaFutures` from scalatest to your test class and then do `ok.futureValue shouldBe Done`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're facing two problems at the same time :

1. Kafka consumer infinitely waits for elements (as said by @dvim), so you need to .take() for it to actually end
2. A kafka consumer group by default will start at the end of the current topic, not the start, and as so won't consume messages posted before it was spinned. You need at a setting to make it start at the beginning of the topic rather than at the end.

Comment: my consumer works at localhost:9092 while my producer works at memory, doesn't it ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Search for "auto.offset.reset" in https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/